# Show multiple images randomly

Tags: php

Would I be able to use

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('1.png');
```

and make it call out multiple random PNG images from a folder?

The website is `livlaughlov.com`, right now it is just using a single PNG and writing post text on it, I want it to randomly grab a PNG from a folder to write text on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) function and [`rand()`](http://php.net/rand):

```
$folder = './dir/to/images/';
$files  = glob($folder.'*.png');
$rand   = rand(0, count($files)-1);

// random png image: $files[$rand];
```

Comment: This?
`$folder = './dir/to/images/';
$files  = glob($folder.'*.png');
$rand   = rand(0, count($files)-1);
$im = imagecreatefrompng($files[$rand]); 
$txt_background = imagecolorallocate ($im, $bg_r, $bg_g, $bg_b); 
$txt_Color = imagecolorallocate ($im, $txt_r, $txt_g, $txt_b); 
$shadow_Color = imagecolorallocate ($im, $shdw_r, $shdw_g, $shdw_b); 
imagettftext ($im, $txt_size, $shdw_angle, $shdw_x, $shdw_y, $shadow_Color, $font, $string); 
imagettftext ($im, $txt_size, $txt_angle, $txt_x, $txt_y, $txt_Color, $font, $string); 
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagePNG($im);
imagedestroy ($im);`